# Possible bug in newsletter?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, newsletter

February 6's newsletter had my question at the very end of its list (under the section "Can you answer these questions?"):

[image]

It says, "answered by *Oscar Lanzi*". However, if you have a look at the [actual question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89970/isocyanides-undergo-addition-reactions-but-cyanides-do-not-why), it was answered by "*Soumik Das*" instead.

What is going on here? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is unanswered in the sense of stack exchange: it does not have an answer with a score higher than zero. You can see that the answer by oscar has a score of -1, so it does not count.

(The deletion probably came later than the newsletter was sent, we would have to know the time when it was composed to compare, so it still shows up there.)

Comment: That is also true. Thanks!

Comment: @Gaurang That is the actual reason. If the answer had a score of one or higher, then you can still blame it on caching. But that simply is not the case. You were asking about a bug: It is not a bug, it is not caching.

Answer (score 7):

Oscar did have an answer, which they subsequently deleted, but most likely after the newsletter had already picked up the question info.

Comment: Well, I couldn't view the deleted answers. I guess this answers my query.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ or [meta meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/260760)